# Prove that $D=\{(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]:x,y \in \mathbb Q\}$ is not a Jordan set

Tags: calculus

Definition of Jordan set: a bounded set $D$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is a Jordan set if its boundary has Jordan content zero

Definition of content zero: $D\subset \mathbb R^2$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finit collection of rectangle $R_k$, $1\leq k\leq n$ whose union cover $D$ and the sum of their area is less than $\epsilon$.

From the definition of this set, I can see that the boundary of $D$ coincides with the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.So it doesn't have Jordan zero, hence $D$ is not Jordan Set. But I don't know how to show it  formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show  that $\overline D=[0,1]^2$ and $\overline{D^c}=\Bbb R^2$?

> The boundary of your set is $\overline D\cap \overline{D^c}$. Now $\overline D=[0,1]^2$, since any point in $[0,1]^2$ may be approximated by one with rational coordinates. The complement $D^c$ is formed by $\Bbb R^2\smallsetminus [0,1]^2$ and those points in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with at least one coordinate irrational. Again, we may approximate any point of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ by an irrational and a rational, and $\overline{\Bbb R^2\smallsetminus [0,1]^2}= \Bbb R^2\smallsetminus (0,1)^2$, so $\overline{D^c}=\Bbb R^2$ and $\partial D=[0,1]$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part, $\mathbb R^2 -(0,1)^2$ mean you take away the interior of the square $[0,1]^2$, then how come you still get $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif It is a general fact that $\overline{X\smallsetminus A}=X\smallsetminus A^\circ$.

Comment: yes, I understand that part, I just don't understnad why $\overline D^c =\mathbb R^2 -D^o =\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif Note I separated the complement in *two* pieces. It happens that one piece amounts to $\Bbb R^2\smallsetminus (0,1)^2$ and the other amounts to $[0,1]^2$, whose union is all of the plane.